# localstorage is behaving differently in IE 11 and Chrome

Tags: local-storage

How to create eventlistner to check the requested tab in IE 11.

```
function handler(e) 
{console.log("hi");}
```

I need to call this handler when there are multiple tabs open, it is working fine in Chrome and FF, but it is getting called in IE even if there is single tab.

Comment: How do you add this function to the event listener ?

Comment: if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("storage", handler, false);
} else if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onstorage", handler);
};
I have added the method like this, it is working fine in Chrome and FF but not in IE.

Comment: Please edit your question to add / update codes.